# IPC through IPCEvent and PublicRender Parameters doesn't work in Liferay 7.3.4

Tags: jsf, liferay, portlet, liferay-7

I use Liferay CE 7.3.4 and I need to use IPC in my portlets so I tried to test most basic communication between two portlets. My first try was with JSF portlet and it didn't work to put it simply it acts as if IPCEvent doesn't exist, the same is for PublicRenderParameters. So I tried doing it in Liferay MVC and I got same results. But when I tried to run this portlets on Liferay 7.2 everything works perfectly.

So I have one very simple question are IPCEvents and PublicRenderParameters still supported in Liferay 7.3, and if they are how to enable them.

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried and post a [mcve]

Comment: I would recommend that you download the com.liferay.faces.demo.jsf.ipc.pub.render.params.portlet WAR artifact and try it in your 7.3 environment. The single WAR contains a "Customers" portlet and a "Bookings" portlet that demonstrates IPC with Public Render Parameters. Source code can be found at https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces-bridge-impl/tree/4.2.0/demo/jsf-ipc-pub-render-params-portlet